# Memcached Tuning Scripts: How to determine efficiency of memcached?

Tags: php, scripting, memcached

Are there any tuning scripts for memcached like there are for mysql (http://www.day32.com/MySQL/)?

I need to know how effective my memcached is being used, and I don't know how to determine that. I can do telnet to the port and run "stats" but I don't know how much is being memory of the memcached memory is being used currently and how many average connections there are to memcached, and other important statistics.

Please let me know if there are any tips or tricks you use to determine how well your memcached service is being used (if there are no standard memcached scripts).

Comment: Membase is really the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be to use cacti monitoring to have full insight into memcached server. Have a look at my cacti graphs
http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/memcached-cache-monitoring-with-cacti

I also recommend memcached admin or similar tool for manual inspection

http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/

art

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool to monitor your environment, do checkout  [Evident ClearStone](http://www.evidentsoftware.com/products/clearstone-for-memcached/). We have tried to make it very useful for developers to know their environment in depth.